# how to make object float in water

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

How to make water pass through pipe with object link leafs and dust https://youtu.be/qGD1bD44B70?t=13s   as seen video i want to make same as like

they would make the leaf float wih water,  I want the water to carry the leaf, as a physical object.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to simulate this with a particle system and force fields.

Comment: Please add more detail to the answer.

Comment: Yeaa, can you please give more info?